# I'm a victim of racism by the border police of Bulgaria

Tags: immigration, discrimination, human-rights

I was excited to visit Bulgaria, I flew all the way to Sofia (Bulgaria), but unfortunately, I was not able to enter it for no reason. I provided everything they wanted me to provide, but no luck (everything was legal). 
They checked out my baggage and they put me in a very dirty prison (in the airport) under surveillance like a criminal, without food or water, even though I told them that I was very thirsty. 
The police in my home country didn't understand what happened because, everything was legal on my side, and they told me maybe I was a victim of racism. 
I contacted the consular officer of Bulgaria in my home country, and she told me that the police officer (a girl) is racist, and I'm not the first case. The consular officer protested several times, but the same thing still happening (the consular officer started crying when she heard my story).

Please, I would like to speak out and put an end to this. What should I do? who should I write to?

Comment: I suppose you could retain an attorney in Bulgaria but it can be quite difficult and expensive to take on a nation.  They have virtually unlimited resources compared to you.  Let me also suggest that you remove the "human-rights" tag from your question.  You have no "right" to enter another sovereign nation regardless of how much you desire to.

Comment: @jwh20 I do understand that entering another country is not a human right, but putting me in a prison with no food or water is against human rights, right?

Comment: I also find it highly questionable that you were actually in "prison" as opposed to some holding area at the airport.

Comment: @jwh20 It looks like a prison in the airport, there is no light in the room (only the light of the aisle), there are security cameras (normal and infrared) everywhere, even in my room, the bed is extremely dirty and cockroaches all over the place, the main door was locked an I can't go anywhere, they locked me in and I was under surveillance.

Comment: You should mention your home country. It makes a difference. Were you visiting for a holiday, or visiting friends? You can be stopped and refused entry at most borders, especially if they suspect you want to stay longer than just for a visit, even if you have a visa. You should have been given a reason for the refusal to let you in, that would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not** take your case to Law Stack Exchange.

You can try to file a lawsuit against Bulgaria and their officials in your specific case. This will be expensive and likely fail.

Or you can try to raise public awareness among Bulgarian voters about stories *like* yours. One example is unlikely to change any policies, but it might *contribute*, just a little bit, in a shift of public opinion. Or it might not. I do not know your nationality or the details of your case, but many in Europe are very much against illegal immigrants, and prepared to err on the side of caution.

- You might contact a tourism industry association, either for Bulgaria or for your specific destination, and point out to them that you *could not spend money in their hotels and restaurants* because you were not allowed in. And that they should do something about it.
- Or you might contact a human rights advocacy group.

Answer (score 4):

I'm very sorry to hear about your situation. Unfortunately, this is too important to trust advice from strangers over the Internet. You should talk to an attorney familiar with Bulgarian immigration law.

@jwh20 is correct; entering another country is not a human right. If they are not allowing you to return to your home country despite your following all laws, that is likely a human rights issue.

This does not necessarily mean you won't be able to get into Bulgaria; if one person is preventing you from entering, an attorney may be able to get that person's decision overturned.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I do understand that entering another country is not a human right, but putting me in a prison with no food or water is against human rights, right?

Comment: Apparently entering a sovereign country is not a human right but perhaps it is one of some description to be treated with dignity and without racial prejudice?

Comment: Again, you are attempting to insert _your_ values or your home country's laws into another context.  Bulgaria does not have a stellar track record in the area of human rights.  I'm not meaning to be insensitive to your situation but when you go places like that you place yourself at some risk of such things happening.

Comment: @JosephP. I find only hearsay that there is anything involving racial prejudice.

Comment: @jwh20 That would seem a question of fact  and thus out of scope for LSE.

Comment: @CryptoBird yes, their treatment of you does sound like a human rights violation. It would not have been one if they had simply sent you back home, but they should at least give you water.

Comment: @Someone The border police put me in that "prison" until they modified my return flight ticket and arranged everything to go back home (everything is on me) and everything happened in the same day.

Comment: @JosephCorrectEnglishPronouns I can’t actually see any evidence of racial prejudice or discrimination.

Comment: Still, it seems to be a given in the question as OP framed it.